# How to access kubernet service from local machine without Port forwarding?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am able to access the elastic service  of GCP project by using kubctl port forwarding in my local system and for that i need to always keep port forwarding command line open.

Is there any way, where we can access these Kubctl services without port forwarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean when you said "I am able to access the elastic service of GCP project by using kubctl port forwarding in my local system", but if you want to have access to your GCP resources from your local, it is necessary to install in your local  the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/?&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=latam-MX-all-es-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-dr-1009133-LUAC0009342&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_431451484985-ADGP_BKWS%20%7C%20Multi%20%7E%20Dev%20%7C%20SDK-KWID_43700043798699670-kwd-610235859304-userloc_1010095&utm_term=KW_google%20cloud%20sdk-ST_Google%20Cloud%20SDK&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIoerGjtnz6wIVXuvjBx3eywABEAAYASAAEgIcvPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). Once you have installed it, you need to install the kubctl as is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart#choosing_a_shell).

Having installed that, and once you have been authenticated correctly to your project, you will have access to your GCP resources (taking into account that you will have access to the same resources that you have access using the console).